# Colors won't change on the multiple axis plotly example

Tags: python, plot, ipython, plotly

I've tried changing the color on the code given in the 'Multiple Axes in Python' example, but the colors don't change.
https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/

ie no matter what you change:

```
titlefont=dict(
    color='rgb(148, 103, 189)'
),
tickfont=dict(
    color='rgb(148, 103, 189)'
```

to, the colors stay the same on the chart

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The colors should change without any problems, see the sample below (also works for RGB colors).

Are you sure that the attributes were put in `legend` (and in `yaxis/2`) and not in `data`?

[image]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[40, 50, 60],
    name='yaxis data',
    marker={'color': 'red'}
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[4, 5, 6],
    name='yaxis2 data',
    yaxis='y2',
    marker={'color': 'blue'}
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Double Y Axis Example',
    yaxis=dict(
        title='yaxis title'
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title='yaxis2 title',
        titlefont=dict(
            color='green'
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color='pink'
        ),
        overlaying='y',
        side='right'
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='multiple-axes-double')
```